# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar todo lo que haya en las etiquetas <p ...> o <span ...> por sólo <p> y solo <span> en PHP?

Tags: php, regex

En PHP tengo un código que me produce un JSON así:

```
{
        "padre": "José Aldazabal",
        "id": 996,
        "texto": "<p class=\"st1\">1. Hechos 4, 32-37<\/p> <p>a) Una de las consecuencias más visibles de la Pascua, para la primera comunidad cristiana, fue esta fraternidad tan hermosa que nos narra el libro de los Hechos. <\/p> <p>Se trata de uno de los «sumarios» que Lucas redacta en los primeros capítulos sobre cómo se desarrollaba la vida de los cristianos de Jerusalén. La vitalidad y la armonía de aquella comunidad están tal vez idealizadas. Basta seguir leyendo y pronto aparecen tensiones y discrepancias. Por ejemplo Ananías y Safira -en una escena que no leemos- no quisieron aceptar eso de poner en común sus bienes. Lucas nos presenta cómo debería ser una comunidad cristiana que cree en Cristo Jesús y sigue su estilo de vida. Y cómo, en efecto, era en buena medida. <\/p> ..."
    }
```

Yo quiero quitar todo lo que haya en las etiquetas `<p>` de apertura. Aparecen por ejemplo clases y otras cosas variables como:

- `<p class=\"st1\">`
- `<p class=\"st2\">`
- `<p class=\"st3\">`
- `<p class=\"t1\">`
- ... etc.

Me pasa lo mismo con etiquetas `<span>`:

- `<span class=\"st3\">`
- `<span class=\"t1\">`
- ... etc.

Yo quiero tener todos los `<p>` sin nada más y todos los `<span>` sin nada más.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

La información viene de una base de datos, y este es el código PHP donde creo el JSON:

```
$json=json_encode($arrData,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$resp=      '
        {"metaLiturgia": {
                "fecha"  : "20190103",
                "tiempo" : "tiempo",
                "semana"   : "semana",
                "mensaje": "msj",
                "salterio": "sal",
                "color":"col",
                "meta": "meta"
        },

"pericopa":"pericopa",
"comentarioCompleto":'.$json."}";
echo $resp;
```

No quiero quitar el dato en la BD, porque me sirve en una página web y para consumirla en una App Android, donde esas etiquetas me están complicando la lectura de voz del texto, por eso quiero quitarlas en la App (además no sirven de nada en ella).

Comment: espero este pedazo de regex le ayude a alguien a responderte `<p(\s[\w=\\\"]+)*\>(.*)<` y agrego como comentario que yo primero haría el replace de una etiqueta y luego de la otra

Comment: Podrias intentar con `preg_replace('/<p(.*?)>/', '<p>', $texto);` lo mismo para los span

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa funciona, ahora me devuelve los datos así: `"texto":"<p>1. Hechos 4, 32-37<\/p> <p>a) Una de las consecuencias más visibles de la Pascua, para la primera comunidad cristiana, fue esta fraternidad...` tal y como quería. Gracias. Lo puedes poner como respuesta.

Comment: Creo que se podría mejorar para hacer la expresión regular genérica para cualquier etiqueta

Comment: @Julio, sería una opción interesante, ¿cómo se puede mejorar?

Answer (score 2):

Podrías probar con lo siguiente:

```
<[a-zA-Z]++\K\s++[^>]+
```

Remplazar por: `nada`

Debería funcionar con cualquier etiqueta.

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/ukoZ6W/2/).

**Explicado:**

```
<              # '<' Literal
[a-zA-Z]++     # Caracter a-z una o más veces, sin retroceso
\K             # Ignorar lo encontrado anteriormente
\s++           # Caracter espacio/tab/salto línea una o más veces, sin retroceso
[^>]+          # Caracter que no sea '>' una o más veces
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar la siguiente expresión regular:

```
/<([a-z]+)[^>]+>/mi
```

#### Descripción:

```
<          # Caracter '<'
(          # Apertura de grupo #1
  [a-z]+   # 1 o mas caracteres de la A a la Z
)          # Cierre de grupo #1
[^>]+      # 1 o mas caracteres distintos de '>'
>          # Caracter `>`

Flags
  m: Multi-linea (Por las dudas tengas saltos de líneas)
  i: Insensible a mayúsculas o minúsculas (Por las dudas tengas tags como <P...>)
```

#### Ejemplo:

```
echo preg_replace('/<([a-z]+)[^>]+>/mi', '<$1>', $texto);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ukB#tab-preg-replace)</kbd>